# sending data stored inside an ArrayList via RMI

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, client-server, rmi

If I want the client to request text data stored inside an ArrayList in the server, how the process of implementation will be using Java RMI ?

A class diagram or a sample code will be great please.

Comment: In other words how to implement an RMI application? Too broad. Find a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Define an interface for both server and client (same package name)*

```
package arrayListRMI;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface IArrayList extends Remote {
    public ArrayList<String> getText()  throws RemoteException;
    public void setText(ArrayList<String> text) throws RemoteException;
}
```

*Define a utility class `Constants.java`*

```
package arrayListRMI;

public class Constants {    
    public static final String RMI_ID = "StackOverflowAnswer";
    public static final int RMI_PORT = 222 ;   
}
```

*Add an implementation for `IArrayList` (in the server side)*

```
package arrayListRMI;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ArrayListImpl  extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IArrayList{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<String> text;

    protected ArrayListImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(ArrayList<String> text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

*So you can instantiate an `ArrayList` of `String` (text) in the server side by instantiating an `ArrayListImpl` and bind it to the `rmiregistry` so that the client can request for it anytime.*

```
ArrayList<String> textRequested = new ArrayList<String>();
textRequested.add("example1");
textRequested.add("example2");
ArrayListImpl arrayListToSend = new ArrayListImpl();
arrayListToSend.setText(textRequested);
```

*Server*

```
package arrayListRMI;

import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws AlreadyBoundException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
            ArrayList<String> textRequested = new ArrayList<String>();
            textRequested.add("example1");
            textRequested.add("example2");
            ArrayListImpl arrayListToSend = new ArrayListImpl();
            arrayListToSend.setText(textRequested);
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Constants.RMI_PORT);
            registry.bind(Constants.RMI_ID, arrayListToSend);
            System.out.println("Server starts....");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*Client*

```
package arrayListRMI;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", Constants.RMI_PORT);
            IArrayList cmp = (IArrayList) registry.lookup(Constants.RMI_ID);
            ArrayList<String> received = cmp.getText();
            System.out.println(received);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*Now run the server. You get this output*

```
Server starts....
```

*Then run the client. You get this output*

```
[example1, example2]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but can you please explain the purpose of the utility class Constants.java ?

Comment: It is just to more organizing your work. And make the RMI connection to the remote object unique through `RMI_ID`. Also if the answer helps you, consider accepting the answer and upvoting. Thanks.

Comment: Did it work for you? Here in my IDE it works perfectly. @AlaaAbuZarifa

Comment: yes it works, but the way i learn it i didn't use ur way to bind the client & the sever .. I use it like this in the sever class ||=>
  IArrayList c = new ArrayListImpl();
   Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:/MyService", c);`

Comment: Either ways are correct. You can use whatever way you want. It is up to you to choose between them ;)

Comment: For me, I have just used the standard way provided by the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) ;)

Comment: ok thax but one last thing,, I'm remaking the code to be GUI .. i wanna store some people with data in the arraylist ,, so the client have GUI with table that views that stored data like 3 columns (name, age, phone#) ! if wanna make it this way, do i have to make more than one arraylist coz essentially i wanna divide the data like a very simple database for user or somthing like that... I hope u get what i mean !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77230/discussion-between-mchaker-and-alaa-abuzarifa).